# Pull-up scheme for Hall effect sensors on a BLDC

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, pullup, hall-effect

I looked around on here, and used google, and couldn't find a direct answer to this question.  Please forgive me if I overlooked something.

I am working on a board to control a BLDC [motor](https://www.anaheimautomation.com/manuals/brushless/L010229%20-%20BLWS23%20Series%20Product%20Sheet.pdf) (BLWS231D-24V-2000) which has a set of integrated Hall effect sensors that I will be using in conjunction with an external capacitive [encoder](https://www.anaheimautomation.com/manuals/encoder/L011742%20-%20ENC-AMT10%20Spec%20Sheet.pdf) (AMT102-V).  I will be powering the sensor with +5V coming from the Driver [IC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8320r.pdf) (TI DRV8323SR) I am using.   Through conversations with an application engineer at the motor manufacturer, I learned that when the Hall effect sensors (open collector output) are floating, I "should" read about 6.3 V, if I were to hook them up to a scope.  The [MCU](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-8387-8-and16-bit-avr-microcontroller-xmega-a4u_datasheet.pdf) (XMEGA128A4U) I am planning to use operates on 3.3 V logic.  Before learning about the approximate voltage from the Hall sensors in their floating state, I was planning on using a pull-up resistor to the 3.3 V supply line that will be coming from a separate linear [regulator](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001826D.pdf) to drive the floating voltage to the logic voltage for my chip.

[image: Planned pull-up scheme]

My question:

Should I set up a resistor divider circuit so that the floating voltage from my Hall sensors is forced to be at or near 3.3 V, or will using the pull-up scheme shown above work?  Or should I be looking for a different solution to the voltage issue all together?  Or is there an issue?  I don't want to damage any pins on my MCU and have to completely re-design the board.  This is my first experiment with hall sensors for motor control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec says...

4.5V min for Hall sensor so you can use 5V and open collector may  pull-up to your 3.3V. I don’t understand open collector and 6.3V floating. Unless that is simply stray leakage voltage from 24V Motor supply with 10M probe. Using 3.3mA to 3.3V with 1K will absorb any stray leakage and possibly 10K as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I was going to query the person I spoke with further regarding the voltage question, but I was on a break from work and ran out of time.  The 6.3V reading didn't make sense to me either, so I'm glad I'm not the only person who thought that sounded odd.  Without knowing how they did their testing I can only speculate, but your idea re: a 10M probe makes sense to me.  Thanks again.

Comment: You’re welcome , I wish more experts would agree as well. (But they are shy )

Comment: These Hall sensors are open *drain* outputs, any voltage seen on the outputs on the off state is just from leakage. Your supply/pull-up scheme is the standard arrangement for a 3.3V controller.

Comment: Thanks @PhilG.  How did you determine that they were OD rather than OC?  From experience, or am I misreading the spec sheet?  The sheet indicates OC, is it incorrect?  (This is why God made EEs to go with MEs.  Which came first is a matter best left to scholars, I suspect).

Comment: I think @PhilG may have it wrong.  Some motors may have open drain for analog amplification, but not these ones.  There is only an open collector note, so 4.7k ought to work with a wide tolerance.

Comment: I may be wrong, but the OC/OD notation is used poorly by many manufacturers, Honeywell especially, who are the likely source for these sensors. The only difference is the saturation voltage, a typical bipolar transistor OC output will be 0.6-0.7V, these are described as 0.4V, which lines up with Honeywell's datasheets (0.4V at 10-30mA depending on series). So long as this stays well below the low threshold of the input, typically 1V, it'll make no difference which it is. On our motors we typically see about 20mV at the 300uA that the 10k pullups put through them.

Comment: Actually the Vce(sat) is due to intrinsic constant and the size of the chip so Vce(sat)/Ice~Rce then Ohm’s Law applies for pull-up to Rce is an approximation so you can get < 10mV if you wanted with OC @PhilG

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist, when you say "Vce(sat) is due to intrinsic constant and the size of the chip" are you referring the ICs present in the Hall sensor or the xmega128A4U in my post?  


Also, when sizing pull-up resistors for the 128A4U, I need to pick a value that will keep the sinking current within the MCUs sink current ratings, right?  I think I remember learning that the pins operate based on voltage readings, and so I just need to avoid sinking too much current.


From I=V/R for 3.3V/4.7K, I get I  = .7mA, and 1mA for a 3.3k resistor.  Any reason to pick one value over another?

Comment: Unrelated, but the driver IC I am using has it's own 3.3V output, with limit of 30mA.  B/c I am adding LEDs to my board, I decided to use the separate linear regulator in my post (regs the 5V output of the driver, set with resistors), to power my MCU/the LEDs.  There are pins on the driver that need pull-up to 3.3V.  Is there any reason not to use the 3.3V output of the driver to pull the voltage up?  It would be easier to route the board this way, but my instinct is to use the same source for all my pull-ups, namely the 3.3V output of the secondary linear regulator.
Thanks so much!

Comment: For open collector pullup, they only need to share a common gnd.  Values can be 100k ohm if you want but more sensitive to stray current noise from crosstalk if you were pulsing high current nearby